# Email in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Below is the code I use to send email, but i don't know if it is correct. My application is based on angularjs 1.4.8.

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("api/SendMail")]
protected void sendmail()
{

    var fromAddress = "xxxk@xxxxx.com";
    var toAddress = "rrrr@rrr.com";
    const string fromPassword = "workufs1234";
    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress);
    mailMessage.To.Add(toAddress);
    mailMessage.Subject = "Documents";
    string messge = "hellooooo";
    string tempmsg = "";
    var messg = @"<html><body><br />Dear  ss ,<br /><br />  <br />";
    mailMessage.To.Add(toAddress);
    string html = messg.ToString();
    AlternateView altView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(html, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(altView);
    mailMessage.Body = messg.ToString();
    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

    SmtpClient mailSender = new SmtpClient("162.222.225.82"); //use this if you are in the development server
    mailSender.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    mailSender.Port = 587;
    mailSender.EnableSsl = true;
    mailSender.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    mailSender.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
    mailSender.Timeout = 40000;
    mailSender.Send(mailMessage);
}
```

How can I test the webapi?

Comment: You could use postman, it is a very good api tester.https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop

Comment: is this httpput or httppost

Comment: Suny Saju what do you mean? Postman can do put, post, get, options, ...

Comment: Have you figured this out yet?